# How do I solve this error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

[image: I want to return both name and email. so Do any one have any idea . How can i return two strings in return statement. Ny one can help]
I want to return both  name and email. so Do any one have any idea . How can i return two strings in return statement.

Comment: Please include any code or error messages as text. Also, your title mentions an error, but it does not appear you are facing any. Please **[edit]** your post to clarify if you are or are not hitting an *error*.

Answer (score 1):

To return **more than one value** (irrespective of data type), you can **return a wrapper** instead.
Wrapper class in apex is used to encapsulate multiple variables irrespective of their data types.

*In case you are using that returned values in a lightning component, we need to use **'@AuraEnabled'** decorator for the variables (as in the code below)*

```
public class <YourClass>{

public WrapperCls <yourMethodName>( <yourParameters> ){
      <your code here>
       
      //while returning values, you can use the wrapper like this
      WrapperCls wrp = new WrapperCls(name, email);
      return wrp;
}

//the wrapper class 
 
public class WrapperCls{
//the variables to be encapsulated
      @AuraEnabled public String nameValue {get; set;}
      @AuraEnabled public String emailValue {get; set;}
// constructor to set the variables
      public WrapperCls(String name, String email){
        nameValue = name:
        emailValue = email;
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Returning a list of strings is probably not ideal, as that forces developers everywhere to remember the order of the return values. A Map or Wrapper (as demonstrated later) is a far better idea.

Comment: sure, thanks for notifying sfdcfox, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can just return the response data. If you always have String values, consider a concrete map instead:

```
Map<String, String> responseData = (Map<String, String>)
  JSON.deserialize(getResponse, Map<String, String>.class);
// ...
return responseData;
```

You'll need to change the return type of the method to match this new format.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good means would be to build an inner class that will let you define a new object (not an sobject). For example, outside of this method, but within the same class file, you can put this code

```
public class NameAndEmail{
    public string nameProperty {get;set;}
    public string emailProperty {get;set;}
}
```

then in the final lines of your method, set the properties and return the object

```
NameAndEmail nae = new NameAndEmail(nameProperty = name, emailProperty = email);
return nae;
```

you'll also have to define the return type in the method signature as NameAndEmail (or whatever you'd like to name the inner class as)

Answer (score -1):

one way is to create wrapper class, for example:

```
public class wrapperClass{
```

Integer int;
String str;
Email email;
}

And use this class as a return value of your method:

```
public static wrapperClass methodToReturnWrapper(){

wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();
return wc;
```

}